# Error starting Apache 2.4 after installing php

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4

I am trying to install apache 2.4 and php following [this tutorial](https://codebriefly.com/how-to-setup-apache-php-mysql-on-windows-10/)

Upon first installing Apache 2.4 and testing it, everything worked fine and it displayed "It worked!". Now, after following along installing php and starting Apache from the Windows services menu, it tells me it "couldn't start Apache2.4 on local computer"

I added it to PATH correctly,
In the config file, I added the code snippet in this way:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/Web/php8"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php8_module "C:/Web/php8/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

I looked at the error log in the apache files but can't seem to really understand anything. This is what the error log shows:

```
AH00455: Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Dec 17 2021 10:17:38
AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Web\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Web/Apache24'
AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4284
AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
AH00430: Parent: Child process 4284 exited successfully.
```

The messages appeared essentially in the same timespan.

EDIT: I tried to start httpd from cmd and it gave me this error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 540 of C:/Web/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php8_module' in file C:/Web/php8/php8apache2_4.dll: No error
```

So, why is apache not starting after I installed php?

EDIT EDIT:
I found the solution: You had to change "php8_module" to "php_module". Now it works just fine.

Comment: There is no way to solve this unless you share the error message in the logs. Don't upload the whole thing. I'm sure you can figure out what's relevant at the end of the error log, whatever that shows up after a start attempt. Nothing consequential to be leaked from that.

Comment: I added the apache error log

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by the PHP installation? Try to comment out the PHP stuff in `httpd.conf` and see if the problem persists. Also, you've installed the correct Apache build, _Thread Safe (TS)_, presumably from [ApacheLounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/)?

Comment: That tutorial doesn't realise that path separator is a regional setting so it's not always a comma. I would double-check paths using the Windows interface (type "path" on Start Menu to find it).

Comment: I corrected path. After commenting out the php part, the problem was gone. And yes I installed the correct build from ApacheLounge

Comment: I added an error message from cmd to the post

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Thanks for your help